# spanish rice ran out of liquid and is getting sticky

Tags: rice

help! My rice is still hard and I have a party coming over. I ran out of liquid and stirred it. Tastes great but center is hard. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding water to let it finish cooking?

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to salvage it, but if it were me, I'd add more liquid, stir it well, cover it with tin foil, and bake in the oven.  The steam from the liquid should be trapped by the tin foil and soften the hard spots.  The amount of liquid you need is a guess at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Add more liquid. If you're worried about diluting the flavour; mix water with a bit of the spices used in your recipe along with chicken stock/broth (if it is you're preferred cooking liquid) and let it steam. Hope this helps :)